# if-then-else statement - logic required

Tags: oracle

Here is the test case with table and insert values

```
create table students (
           name varchar2(25 BYTE),
           joined_date DATE,
           exam_type VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
           SCORE NUMBER(2,1),
           CUT_OFF_DATE DATE
     );
        insert into students values('john','26-mar-14','SCREEN',7.6,'10-apr-14');
        insert into students values('john','10-Apr-14','RETEST',8.0,'10-apr-14');
```

I am trying to return the unique record with the score of that student name. I use CASE, but it really does not act as 'IF-THEN-else' like using a control statement.

```
select name,
       joined_date,
       case 
            ---something like IF statment if below[b] statement 1[/b] --is true then it
            --should return below statement
            when exam_type ='SCREEN' and score between 8.0 and 10.0
            then score
            ----[b]statement 2[/b] --if above expr fails, the below to be executed
            when exam_type ='RETEST' and score between 8.0 and 10.0
            and joined_date >= cut_off_date
            then score
            else null
       end result
from students;

output
    NAME    JOINED_DATE RESULT
    john    26-03-14    
    john    10-04-14    8
```

in the above result set, I need only the score '8' and 'John' as a unique records only? like this there are more then millions of records to be computed.

Logic needed? Please

Comment: You don't want the first record because `Result` is `NULL` - is that the case?

Comment: yup, It need to return result as single row result. in the output it is Result '8'

Answer (score 0):

This is default Behavior of CASE WHEN statement that it will put NULL when none of the condition becomes TRUE. you can change your query as below to get Expected outcome.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 select name,
       joined_date,
       case 
            ---something like IF statment if below[b] statement 1[/b] --is true then it
            --should return below statement
            when exam_type ='SCREEN' and score between 8.0 and 10.0
            then score
            --[b]statement 2[/b] --if above expr fails, the below to be executed
            when exam_type ='RETEST' and score between 8.0 and 10.0
            and joined_date >= cut_off_date
            then score
       end result
 from students
 ) main where main.result IS NOT NULL;
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53cf7/3)

Comment: assume if have more records

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/914e9/1

I need to the first occurred record ? how to get the logic

Comment: Always first one or max from all or any other criterias need to fulfill?

Comment: yup, always the first occurred condition which returns true for "SCREENED' students. if the first records files, then check the second  record... like that. hope this clear

Comment: if you have mulitple students name, does it gives the result based on the each student?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11f3a/1

Comment: Thanks alot for your help,could yo help in brining in PL/SQL code? using If-then -else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. The single score is selected based on the this criteria: the highest score of the student, with earliest joined_date and cut_off_date and least exam_type value (alphabetically).

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  s1.name
  ,s1.joined_date
  ,s1.exam_type
  ,s1.score
  ,s1.cut_off_date
FROM students s1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT name, joined_date, exam_type, score, cut_off_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY score desc, joined_date, exam_type, cut_off_date) rn
 FROM students
 WHERE 
     (exam_type ='SCREEN' and score between 8.0 and 10.0)
  or (exam_type ='RETEST' and score between 8.3 and 10.0 and joined_date >= cut_off_date)
) s2
ON s1.name = s2.name
AND s1.joined_date = s2.joined_date
AND s1.exam_type = s2.exam_type
AND s1.cut_off_date = s2.cut_off_date
WHERE s2.rn = 1;
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11f3a/13)</kbd>